# Oracle check constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl, check-constraints

How do you make if constraints in Oracle SQL?

```
Create Table A(
b varchar(25) primary key,
c varchar(25),
constraint b_1
check(b='name' and c != 'notallowed')
);
```

The following should **not** work:

```
Insert into A values('name','notallowed');
```

But this *should* work:

```
Insert into A values('notname','notallowed');
```

How can I fix my constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this

```
check ((b='name' and c != 'notallowed') or b != 'name')
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the only illegal combination is `b='name' and c='notallowed'`. If this is correct, you can express this with the `not` operator:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    b varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    c varchar(25),
    CONSTRAINT b_1
    CHECK(NOT(b = 'name' AND c = 'notallowed'))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of writing this is:

```
create Table A
(
  b varchar(25) primary key,
  c varchar(25),
  constraint b_1 check ( (b,c) not in (('name', 'notallowed')) )
);
```

(Yes, the duplicate parentheses around the `IN` list are required in Oracle)